# Google+ API, call API without access token

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I implemented a Google+ and a Facebook login button and got access token successfully. However I didn't save it in my server. For new business, I need to get display name and image of authorized users.

For Facebook integration, I can use :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userId?fields=picture.width(720).height(720),name&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

Are there any similar way for Google+ API to get public information of Google+ user (image, name, email..) without the missing access token?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has something called a public API key.  Public API keys can only be used to access Public data.  So if the user in question hasn't set something on there profile public you wont be able to see it.

You will need to go to [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) an register your application there you will be able to create a public key and enable the google+ api.

request (note the key on the end):

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/+LindaLawton?key=XXXXX

Response

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"Sh4n9u6EtD24TM0RmWv7jTXojqc/t4cdVyNXc5UKH1p-n75jDwEzvvw\"",
 "occupation": "Google Developer Expert, BIA Developer at Targit",
 "skills": "Experience primarily in regards Microsoft products, Visual Studio, Bids, C# and asp.net.  Past experience with PHP,JavaScript, MySQL and Linux.  In recent years I have begun focusing on Business Intelligence, Data Warehousing, SQL Server / Analysis Services / Integration Services.   Experience with OAuth2, Google Analytics API, Google Drive SDK.",
 "gender": "female",
 "urls": [
  {
   ...
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "117200475532672775346",
 "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Lawton",
  "givenName": "Linda"
 },
 "tagline": "Google Developer Expert 2014 - 2017",
 "braggingRights": "Extreme Beekeeper first to recorded an Hive inspection using Google Glass with out a veil on.",
 "aboutMe": "\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cb\u003eBackground\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eI have been working as an application developer since 1995. I have worked with a number of database systems Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and MySQL.  In recent years I have been mainly working with Microsoft products, Visual Studio, SSIS, and C#.   I the past I worked a lot with web development PHP, JavaScript, Ajax, power-builder,  Cobol and ASP.net.\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eWhile I have done front end development in the past. I find working with backed development working on automated systems fascinating.    I have spent the last 5 years creating custom SSIS (Dlls), and services and APIs for the cloud (Azure).\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cb\u003eGoogle API Addiction\u003c/b\u003e \u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eIn 2012 I began working with the Google APIs, starting with the Google Analytics API.  I learned to appreciate the fact that Google is so open and willing to give us access to their systems. I started blogging about how to use the APIs writing short tutorials with sample projects.   \u003ca href=\"http://www.daimto.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eDaimto - Data Import Tutorials\u003c/a\u003e.   This along with my presents on a number of \u003ca href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eDeveloper forms\u003c/a\u003e lead me to discovered by Google.  I became one of the first \u003ca href=\"https://developers.google.com/experts/+LindaLawton\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eGoogle Developer Experts for Google Analytics\u003c/a\u003e.  \u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eI also help support the \u003ca href=\"https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eGoogle APIs client Library for .NET\u003c/a\u003e which provides simple, flexible, and powerful access to Google APIs such as Drive, YouTube, Calendar, Storage and Analytics.\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cb\u003eLife\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003eI grew up in a small town in \u003ca href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth,_Massachusetts\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eMassachusetts\u003c/a\u003e, USA, I moved to \u003ca href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denmark\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eDenmark \u003c/a\u003ein 1998 and have lived here since. I have a 22 year old daughter.  My hobbies include reading science fiction, painting, and gardening.   \u003c/div\u003e",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAdVM/sHkU9F-AwwQ/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "organizations": [
  {
   ...
  }
 ],
 "placesLived": [
  {
   ...
  }
 ],
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 1879,
 "verified": false,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uDdUhB6o9WkVDpEft9VMBS5hm8nYTh2eCf_2RQ297u61U0y-98WBNSrlGvKz6ksHiuV20Rc-=s630-fcrop64=1,099f2649dfffc883",
   "height": 696,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": -7,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```